# A clarification on $L_{loc}^2$ process and stochastic exponential

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals, local-martingales

In the book by A. Pascucci (PDE and Martingale Methods in Option Pricing) I have found the following definition of $\mathbb{L}^2_{\text{loc}}$ process.

[image]

Later (pp. 329-330) for a process $\lambda\in\mathbb{L}^2_{loc}$ the exponential martingale associated to $\lambda$ is defined as

$$
Z_t^{\lambda} = \exp\left(-\int_{0}^t\lambda_s\,dW_s-\frac{1}{2}\,\int_{0}^t\left|\lambda_s\right|^2\,ds\right),\quad t\in\left[0,T\right], \quad (10.1).
$$

What puzzles me is Lemma 10.1:

[image]

Since the exponential martingale is defined only for $\lambda$ in the class $\mathbb{L}^2_{loc}$, condition (10.3) in the Lemma 10.1 should be immediately guaranteed by (4.34) in Definition 4.33. Where am I wrong?

Comment: As far as I understand, the constant $C$ does not depend on $\omega$; therefore (10.3) does, in general, not follow from (4.34).

Comment: Otherwise said 10.3 implies 4.34 but not the other way around. Or again almost sure finiteness  does not implies almost sure boundedness but the opposite is true. Best regards

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, now I am looking for an example in which (4.34) is true but (10.3) is not, any suggestions?

Comment: For example I consider $\Omega=[0,1]$ with the Lebsegue measure $\lambda(\Omega)=1$. Then the random variable $X(\omega)=\frac{1}{1-\omega}$ is such that $\lambda(\{\omega|X(\omega)<\infty\})=1$ nevertheless it does not exists a $C$ (which is $\omega$-independent) such that $\lambda(\{\omega|X(\omega)<C\})=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Fix a random variable $X$ (measurable at time zero if you like) which is finite but not in $L^\infty$, then define $\lambda_t = X$ for all $t$. Then

$$
\int_0^T \lambda_t^2\,dt = T X^2.
$$

By assumption $T X^2 < \infty$ for all $T, \omega$, but there is no $C$ such that $TX^2 \leq C$ almost surely, as this would imply $X \in L^\infty$.

The difference is that (4.34) lets the constant depend on $\omega$, whereas (10.3) does not.

Comment: That's exactly what we have already discussed in the above comments, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, and I also give an example of a process f or which one condition holds but the other doesn't. The comments give a random variable, not a process.

Comment: A random variable is a (trivial) example for a stochastic process - and that's exactly what you used in this answer.

Comment: Indeed, this entire question "trivial," but I am not OP, and I do not presume that OP is familiar with all the examples that we call trivial, else OP would not have asked this question. If you disagree and feel that my answer is nothing more than a repetition of what appears in the comments, please downvote and comment with any constructive criticism that you may have on improving my answer.